# Paths like /usr/bin, /usr/sbin are still being added to $PATH even without /etc/paths

Tags: path, zsh

By default, my $PATH environment variable looks like this:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/zfs/bin:/Users/nate/.nix-profile/bin:/run/current-system/sw/bin:/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin
```

I use Nix, and I wanted my nix-profile/bin to be ahead of /usr/bin. I was testing some solutions, and I wanted to see what would happen if I renamed /etc/paths so that they are no longer included.

Starting a new shell, I now get this:

```
/Users/nate/.nix-profile/bin:/run/current-system/sw/bin:/nix/var/nix/profiles/default/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin
```

This convieniently seems to have solved my problem, as the problematic paths are now after my nix-related ones (albeit in a different order), but I'm curious as to what exactly is adding these to my $PATH, if not /etc/paths?

Comment: As I pointed out in your other question on Reddit, why aren't you just setting your path to what you want it to be, versus renaming system files?

Comment: @Marc Wilson I mean, at this point I'm kinda just curious. But for the explanation: The nix-related paths are prepended to $PATH in nix-daemon.sh already, which is called in /etc/zshrc. I'd rather not mess with the nix-related stuff or 'clutter' my .zshrc by re-adding those same nix paths except afterwards.

Comment: So I see that the /etc/paths is used by path_helper, and if I remove that from ~/.zprofile that's sort of a cleaner(?) solution than renaming /etc/paths outright. I guess for my real question (rearranging the nix-profile paths) there might be a proper Nix way to solve this, but I'm still interested in finding out what's seemingly adding these same paths again.

Comment: Also, I'd have duplicates in my $PATH, wouldn't I? Unless I edit nix-daemon.sh. Thx

Comment: Look at /etc/zprofile (yes paths should be set in zshenv but Apple can't read)

Comment: Actually you should use `ksh` instead of `zsh`, which (zsh) is a maze of twisty little configuration files.  But I digress. ^_^